# How does postgres Palloc using memory context

Tags: c, postgresql, memory-management

I am working on postgresql extension currently and got a doubt regarding memory contexts. In postgres source code and documentation it is mentioned that using palloc will allocate memory in the memory context pointed by CurrentMemoryContext(global var) but when I see postgres internal code all I can see is malloc so how does switching between context result in memory allocating in the switched context only. See the below postgres code for reference.

```c
void *
palloc(Size size)
{
    return pg_malloc_internal(size, 0);
}

static inline void *
pg_malloc_internal(size_t size, int flags)
{
    void       *tmp;

    /* Avoid unportable behavior of malloc(0) */
    if (size == 0)
        size = 1;
    tmp = malloc(size);
    if (tmp == NULL)
    {
        if ((flags & MCXT_ALLOC_NO_OOM) == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, _("out of memory\n"));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        return NULL;
    }

    if ((flags & MCXT_ALLOC_ZERO) != 0)
        MemSet(tmp, 0, size);
    return tmp;
}
```

Also just curious how would inline work here. Wouldn't  the compiler just ignore it?

Comment: That's not the right palloc code. You need to look at the backend context palloc code e.g. https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/5abbd97fef6f18eef91bfed7d2057c39bd204702/src/backend/utils/mmgr/mcxt.c#L1226

Comment: @AnyaShenanigans Got it. That was a silly mistake my clangd setup was not showing the backend palloc. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the front-end (client) code in `src/common/fe_memutils.c`, which is not used by the database server. Instead, you should look at the backend code in `src/backend/utils/mmgr/mcxt.c`.

For a detailed explanation of memory contexts, see [`src/backend/utils/mmgr/README`](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/utils/mmgr/README). Memory contexts are PostgreSQL's internal memory management tool. They grow automatically by bigger extents (using `malloc()`) if needed, but `palloc()` only returns a pointer to an area in a memory context that PostgreSQL knows is unused. You "allocate" memory from a memory context that lives as long as you need it (a database transaction, the composition of a result row, ...) and you don't have to explicitly free the memory, since the whole context gets reset or destroyed at the appropriate time.

In short, memory contexts reduce the overhead of memory management and prevent memory leaks.

Comment: Yeah got it. I read about the contexts but was seeing the frontend palloc due to that I couldn't understand how it works. Thanks :)